# Index out of bounds exception: cant figure out what is happening? School Assignment

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my first time using stackoverflow for a question that I need to ask, so hopefully I can get some help. This is a school assignment that I am working on, and although I have already turned it in and am going to change the code pretty drastically soon, I would like to figure out what is wrong first. This is basically a purchase history program, where the past purchases are stored and can be accessed as receipts with a 'next' and 'back' button. There is no file access, and all the data is generated randomly. The random data generation wasn't a requirement of the assignment, but I wanted to do it that way as a learning experience.

On to the question, what is going on with this error?

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at farmmark.Storage.getItems(Storage.java:36)
at farmmark.Gui.buttonActionNext(Gui.java:415)
at farmmark.Gui$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Gui.java:632)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6290)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6055)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4653)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:648)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

There is a lot of code, probably too much to post here, so here is a link to the source:
http://www.mediafire.com/?3ogc334vwh6t7k6

Here are the spots of code where the error occurs:

at farmmark.Storage.getItems(Storage.java:36)

```
public static String[] getItems(int select)
{
    return itemList.get(select);
}
```

at farmmark.Gui.buttonActionNext(Gui.java:415)

```
String items[] = Storage.getItems(counter);
```

at farmmark.Gui$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Gui.java:631)

```
else if(sel.equals("Next"))
        {
            jtxtItems.setText(null);
            jtxtPrices.setText(null);
            jtxtSkus.setText(null);
            jtxtCase.setText(null);
            jtxtVend.setText(null);
            panel.removeAll();
            buttonActionNext();
        {
```

Any help would be great, keep in mind I have only been programming in java for 8 weeks :P. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `itemList.get(select)` is selecting some index that's out of the list's bounds.  What's the value of `select`?

Comment: Have you tried going through your program with a debugger?

Comment: The link you provided thows up (fake) popups with "Virus alert" messages...

Comment: Yeah I keep attempting to debug it with no success, and it doesn't help that I while running the program I can't get variables to show up in NetBeans unless I run it to a certain line of code. Louis - the value of select would be the counter(receipt number) which refers to 10 different receipts that are supposedly generated.

Comment: I've used mediafire without any problems before... where else could I upload code?

Comment: you should remember that arrays start at index 0, so if you have an array with 10 elements, object 1 is at index 0 and the last object is at index 9.

Comment: Just as an update, I have solved the problem with accessing an array element that didn't exist. I removed some unneeded arrays and tried to keep it as simple as possible. I also implemented a sort of global counter that helps keep track of receipts and the number of items on each receipt. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where to look:

```
at farmmark.Storage.getItems(Storage.java:36)
```

Here's the method:

```
public static String[] getItems(int select)
{
    return itemList.get(select);
}
```

The value for `select` is either less than zero or greater than `(itemList.length-1)`.

Run in a debugger, set a breakpoint at that line, and see what's up.

I don't see where either itemList or select is set.  Take a look at those methods as well.

Just curious - why is that method static?

Comment: Most of my stuff is static except for in the Gui class, I guess it is just how I've been writing my code and have stuck with it.

Comment: I would have expected it to be a class member; your way is fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `farmmark.Gui$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Gui.java:632)` and see that value is passed to `Gui.buttonActionNext()`, as that value is passed on to `Storage.getItems()` which ends up naming an index that is larger than the size of the list (-1).

It is also possible that there are no items in the list (`Storage.itemList`) to begin with, in which case you will get this exception, regardless of the passed-on value

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you have a lot to learn.
How about you start by wrapping a little check before you try to access you list item like this:

```
public static String[] getItems(int select)
{
    if (select < itemList.size()) {
        return itemList.get(select);
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException("We cannot access an item that does not exist");
    }
}
```

Then, try to find out why the calling code is trying to access the item that does not exist. Read the stack trace, it will tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: OBS: this is just as a learning exercise... you don't want to throw an Exception like this (otherwise, you wouldn't need the check, just let the List implementation keep throwing the IndexOutOfBoundsException)... but this simply makes the problem clear: you cannot access an index which is equal or larger than the list size, because indexes start from 0 and end at list.size()-1. Good luck.